# find the order of the element $a^{-1}b?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group. If $a$ and $b$ are two elements of order $8$ and $10$
respectively, then the order of the element $a^{-1}b$ is

choose the correct option

$a. 80$

$b. 18$

$c. 2$

$d. 40$

**My attempt** :I think option $a$ is  correct

$|a^{-1}|=|a|=8$ .We know that $$\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)=\frac{mn}{\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)}$$

$\implies |a^{-1}b|=\operatorname{lcm}(|a^{-1}|,|b|)\operatorname{gcd}(|a^{-1}|,|b|)=\operatorname{lcm}(8,10)\operatorname{gcd}(8,10)=40.2=80$.

**Edit**:let  $r=|a^{-1}b|\implies r|\operatorname{lcm(m,n)}\implies r=\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)\operatorname{lcm(m,n)}$

Comment: With the exception of $\lvert a^{-1}\rvert=8$, I don't understand your logic. Could you please give the full statement of the theorem by which you are computing the order of the product?

Comment: I think the answer is 40, being the lcm. $(a^{-1})^{40}=b^{40}=e$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio second isomorphism theorem

Comment: @Blitzer $\gcd(8,10)\neq 1$

Comment: @Blitzer You are correct if gcd equals $1$

Comment: @jasmine I asked for the full statement of the theorem you were using, not for its name. Do you mean: "Given a group $G$, $H<G$ and $N\trianglelefteq G$, then $HN<G$ , $N\trianglelefteq HN$, $H\cap N\trianglelefteq H$ and the map $h(H\cap N)\mapsto hN$ is an isomorphism from $H/(H\cap N)$ to $HN/N$"?

Comment: okay nice @SassatelliGiulio  for example take$ G=\mathbb{Z} $,$H=<m>$ ,$N=<n> $ then  $HN=gcd(m,n)$  and   $H\cap N=Lcm(m,n)$

Comment: @jasmine In $\Bbb Z_{40},$ there are elements of order $8$ and of order $10$ but no element of order $80.$

Comment: okay @AnneBauval nice example

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio let $r=|a^{-1}b|\implies r|lcm(m,n)\implies r=gcd(m,n)lcm(m,n)$

Comment: @jasmine Excuse me, is this a guessing game about what you've done 1 hour ago? You've written "I think" et cetera. The considerations that informed your work are independent on what we're saying right now. We weren't there to tell you: "The Dick Hammerbush theorem says yada yada."; "Ok, then look at this example"; "Oh, but furthermore this and this..."

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio  Sorry, my apologies

Comment: @jasmine The implication $r\mid \operatorname{lcm}(m,n)\Rightarrow r=\operatorname{gcd}(m,n)\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$ is unwarranted and false. In fact, we could argue that it's hardly ever true.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Hint:* Note that

$$\begin{align}
(a^{-1}b)^{40}&=a^{-40}b^{40}\\
&=(a^8)^{-5}(b^{10})^4\\
&=e^{-5}e^4\\
&=e.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

The order of $a^2$ and $b^2$ are respectively $4$ and $5,$ which are coprime. The order of $(ab)^2$ is [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/526409) $20,$ which is even. This proves that the order of $ab$ is exactly $40.$